# Google play App Bundels upload error "com.example"

Tags: android, apk, google-play-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvWA0.png)I have created a signed app as a bundle (.aab) I now want to publish this in the Playstore via Console. After uploading the app-release.aab file, I get an error saying "The use of "com.example" is restricted. Please use a different package name."

But I have changed the package name to myapp, see pictures.

Can someone help me in a hurry?thanks :,)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KGNC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rcgy.png)

Watched youtube and the internet :(

Comment: Have you change "namespace" and "applicationId" in build.gradle file inside app folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Ctrl+Shift+F (or Edit -> Find -> Find in Files...) combination in Android Studio and find "com.example" in your project. Also check build.gradle.kts file, you an find package name there. And another option check your AndroidManifest.xml, there is the top tag  which contains "package" field

Comment: Thanks! I added the photo.. I found four times come.example.myapp and one time com.example.myapp.R - what do I have to do? Change all to myapp and myapp.R ?

Comment: I have all com.example.myapp edited to myapp 

But now it says "Manifest merger failed : Package name 'myapp' at position AndroidManifest.xml:2:1-30:12 should contain at least one '.' (dot) character
" after compiling :(

Comment: Do what it says. Add a dot. Do you have an own URL? Use that. For example 'com.ninozefix.myapp'.

Comment: i made them com.ninozefix.myapp but now R is making problems, it says now after compiling: "error: package com.example.myapp does not exist
import com.example.myapp.R;"

Comment: i changed the the package from com/example/myapp to com/ninozefix/myapp and also with cmd+shift+f the other com.example.myapp manualy to com.ninozefix.myapp. But now it doesnt compile anymore cuz of the import com.example.myapp.R       ** Please help, I go crazy with this right now -.- **